# Firestore data change after 24 hour from Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to change only the ***send*** value after 24 hours from orderSendUpdate created. I do this

```
exports.orderSendUpdate = functions.firestore.document('Order/{id}').onCreate(async (change, context) => {

    const orderId = change.after.id;
    
    //this change is hapend after 24 hour from orderSendUpdate created
    firestore.collection('Order').doc(orderId).update({send: true});
        
    return Promise.resolve()
});
```

Comment: Creating a dynamic schedule for a function is hard. You might want to use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks). Let me know you are interested and I'll post an answer. That involves creating a task when a new order is placed and set the execution time in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub to trigger a Cloud Function. According to this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) provided by gcp this are the steps, in summary, that you need to follow:

1. You need to create a Cloud function with the trigger `Cloud Pub/Sub`
2. Create a Cloud Scheduler job and specify the frequency and select the `Pub/Sub` from the Target dropwon.
3. Run the the job with Cloud Scheduler